# Metal on the iOS Simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, metal

I got a Metal Lib, and to use it with Pods I had to use the `MetalPerformanceShadersProxy`, as cocoapods is tested agains a simulator.

Tho now in 2019 with Metal support in the simulator, it would be awesome to actually run my apps in the simulator and skip the proxy.

Tho when trying to build an app on the iOS simulator, with my metal lib, I get the following error:

> Target OS is incompatible: library was not compiled for the simulator

Valid Architectures: `arm64`, `i386` & `x86_64`.

Supported Platforms: `iphonesimulator`, `iphoneos` & `macosx`.

Not sure how to compile my Metal Lib for the simulator.

**Update:**

I ended up building different libs for device and simulator.

Comment: This might be a cocoapods problem or a problem with one of your dependencies that does not have `iphonesimulator` in its supported platforms

Comment: I need help with it too. I compile my metalib with: `xcrun -sdk iphonesimulator metallib *.air -o defaultiOSSimulator.metallib`. but still receive this error. Maybe you did something else?

Comment: ahh I forgot about `xcrun -sdk iphonesimulator metal -c $i -o $(basename -s .metal $i).air`